# TimeBeginPeriod / TimeEndPeriod Sequence

Tags: .net, windows, winapi

I've two Windows .NET libraries A and B. Library A has TimeBeginPeriod(1) and TimeEndPeriod(1) while Library B has TimeBeginPeriod(5) and TimeEndPeriod(5). I've notice lately (after their [behavor change](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2020/10/04/windows-timer-resolution-the-great-rule-change/)) that when the Library B will do TimeEndPeriod(5) Library A looses TimeBeginPeriod(1).

Can you have different time periods within the same application without the one affect the other? I mean I don't mind if the (5) will be affected by (1) but it is crucial that end(5)  will not affect the begin(1)!

```
LibA TimeBeginPeriod(1)
.... LibB TimeBeginPeriod(5)
.... LibB TimeEndPeriod(5)    <- Does this cancel TimeBeginPeriod(1)?
LibA TimeEndPeriod(1)
```

[Update]

Test Code

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static long freq;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            QueryPerformanceFrequency(out freq);

            Console.WriteLine("Begin");
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());

            TimeBeginPeriod(1);
            Console.WriteLine("TimeBeginPeriod(1)");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());

            TimeBeginPeriod(15);
            Console.WriteLine("TimeBeginPeriod(15)");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());

            Console.WriteLine("TimeEndPeriod(15)");
            TimeEndPeriod(15);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());

            TimeEndPeriod(1);
            Console.WriteLine("TimeEndPeriod(1)");


            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine("End");
        }

        private static string CalcSleep1()
        {
            QueryPerformanceCounter(out long ticks1);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            QueryPerformanceCounter(out long ticks2);
            return (new TimeSpan((long)(1000 * 10000 * (ticks2 - ticks1) / (double)freq))).ToString();
        }


        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(out long lpPerformanceCount);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(out long lpFrequency);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeBeginPeriod", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint TimeBeginPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeEndPeriod", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint TimeEndPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern int timeGetDevCaps(ref TIMECAPS ptc, int cbtc);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct TIMECAPS
        {
            internal int wPeriodMin;

            internal int wPeriodMax;
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Begin
00:00:00.0130730
00:00:00.0154164
TimeBeginPeriod(1)
00:00:00.0019935
00:00:00.0019148
00:00:00.0019145
00:00:00.0019203
00:00:00.0023354
TimeBeginPeriod(15)
00:00:00.0019916
00:00:00.0018920
00:00:00.0019412
00:00:00.0019411
00:00:00.0019336
TimeEndPeriod(15)
00:00:00.0019918
00:00:00.0019300
00:00:00.0019671
00:00:00.0019524
00:00:00.0019399
TimeEndPeriod(1)
00:00:00.0152576
00:00:00.0148129
End
```

It seems that the in-between TimeBeginPeriod(15) / TimeEndPeriod(15) does not affect TimeBeginPeriod(1). Except if that happens only on different assemblies (didn't tested yet)

Comment: So, which Windows version are you running on exactly ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod#remarks

Comment: Windows 10 Pro [Version 10.0.19043.1165]

Comment: OK let's forget for the moment the 'effect'. The question is if you have two time periods one within the other, how do they affect each other?

Comment: There's no concept of "time periods" within a process, just one value per process. Think as `timeBeginPeriod(value)` implementation as `processValue = Min(processValue, value)` and `timeEndPeriod(value)` implementation as `if (processValue == value) processValue = defaultValue`. Otherwise you have another problem in your test, you're using 15 but using 15 will in general have the same effect as 1, as the standard clock resolution is 15.625ms. Try 16 instead.

Comment: There is a bug in my application and trying to find where and why. The LibB can be used from other applications and it doesn't require timeBeginPeriod(1) but it does require (5). I don't understand what you mean that the timeBeginPeriod(15) has the same effect as the timeBeginPeriod(1)? How is that possible?

Comment: I think I've found the bug. If I use timeBeginPeriod(1) and underlying lib uses the same and then does timeEndPeriod(1). That affects mine as well.

Comment: Wrong, timeBeginPeriod/timeEndPeriod stack works as it suppose to work. So, something else happens in my code between those calls. I might need to add locks on time calls.

Comment: You may be interested to know that the StopWatch class uses `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency`. You have Windows 10 21H1, so the `TimeBeginPeriod` setting is per-Process (it looks like you have a single Process). But *setting a higher resolution does not improve the accuracy of the high-resolution performance counter*

Comment: I used QueryPerformanceCounter just in the Test Code above. A way to find out what is the current timePeriod as there is no other way to find out? In my application I just care about how much the Thread.Sleep will actually sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By coding my application's logic with a smaller example I was able to reproduce and identify a serious Windows bug. <s>It happens when you load an assembly dynamically.</s> You can download the Solution and/or Compiled [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UDNt-KbwW24aPymF4TIQZia_Apb2V5Ea/view?usp=sharing)

Update: It happens on both static/dynamic. It has different behavior when the global timer changes. What my application was doing was the following which Windows doesn't like:

```
.... LibB TimeBeginPeriod(5)
LibA TimeBeginPeriod(1)
.... LibB TimeEndPeriod(5)    <- This affects TimeBeginPeriod(1) goes back to 15ms - and it happens when the global timer is already to 1ms? - 
LibA TimeEndPeriod(1)
```

I would bet this issue affects a number of applications out there, as they don't really know what the underlying libraries doing with the Time periods.

(Copy the Class12 dll to the Console application output)

Class11

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public abstract class ClassAbstract
    {
        public abstract void StartSample(uint ms);
        public abstract void EndSample(uint ms);
        public abstract void PrintSample();
    }

    public class Class11
    {
        static long freq;

        public Class11()
        {
            QueryPerformanceFrequency(out freq);
        }

        private static string CalcSleep1()
        {
            QueryPerformanceCounter(out long ticks1);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            QueryPerformanceCounter(out long ticks2);
            return (new TimeSpan((long)(1000 * 10000 * (ticks2 - ticks1) / (double)freq))).ToString();
        }

        public void StartSample(uint ms)
        {
            TimeBeginPeriod(ms);
            Console.WriteLine($"TimeBeginPeriod({ms})");

            PrintSample();
        }

        public void EndSample(uint ms)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"TimeEndPeriod({ms})");
            TimeEndPeriod(ms);
        }

        public void PrintSample()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
        }


        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(out long lpPerformanceCount);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(out long lpFrequency);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeBeginPeriod", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint TimeBeginPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeEndPeriod", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint TimeEndPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Class12

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

using ClassLibrary1;

namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class12 : ClassAbstract
    {
        static long freq;

        public Class12()
        {
            QueryPerformanceFrequency(out freq);
        }

        private static string CalcSleep1()
        {
            QueryPerformanceCounter(out long ticks1);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            QueryPerformanceCounter(out long ticks2);
            return (new TimeSpan((long)(1000 * 10000 * (ticks2 - ticks1) / (double)freq))).ToString();
        }

        public override void StartSample(uint ms)
        {
            TimeBeginPeriod(ms);
            Console.WriteLine($"TimeBeginPeriod({ms})");

            PrintSample();
        }

        public override void EndSample(uint ms)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"TimeEndPeriod({ms})");
            TimeEndPeriod(ms);
        }

        public override void PrintSample()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
            Console.WriteLine(CalcSleep1());
        }


        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(out long lpPerformanceCount);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(out long lpFrequency);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeBeginPeriod", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint TimeBeginPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeEndPeriod", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint TimeEndPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

ConsoleApp

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

using ClassLibrary1;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static Class11 class11;
        static ClassAbstract class12;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            class11 = new Class11();

            var assembly =  Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.GetFullPath(@"ClassLibrary2.dll"));
            ClassAbstract class12 = (ClassAbstract) Activator.CreateInstance(assembly.GetTypes()[0]);

            // Behavior changes while System global time period changes
            class12.StartSample(5); // Bug here we get 1ms instead of 5ms
            class11.StartSample(1);
            class12.EndSample(5);
            class11.PrintSample(); // Bug Here we get 15 ms period instead of 1ms
            class11.EndSample(1);
        }
    }
}
```